# Better way to trigger color change based on displayed text

Tags: c#, wpf, textblock, dependencyobject

1. I have a `struct` class that records a value and a check, which simply says whether it is good or bad.

```
    public enum StressCheck
    {
        Good,
        Bad
    }   

    public struct Stress
    {
        public Stress(double stressValue, StressCheck check)
        {
            StressValue = stressValue;
            Check = check;
        }
        public double StressValue { get; set; }               
        public StressCheck Check { get; set; }
    }
```

2. I want to create a `TextBlock` whose background becomes red when the value is 'Bad'. This is what I am doing at the moment in the XAML of my user control.

```
<UserControl x:Class="ScienceProgram.UserControls.DataCellCheck"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             x:Name="parent">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="CheckStress" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TB,Path=Text}" Value="Good">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=TB,Path=Text}" Value="Bad">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="1" DataContext="{Binding ElementName=parent}" Width="100">
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource CheckStress}" Text="{Binding Path=Value}" />
        <TextBlock x:Name="TB"  Text="{Binding Path=Check}" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    </Grid>
```

and the standard code-behind for dependency objects "Value" and "Check"

```
    public partial class DataCellCheck : UserControl
    {
        public DataCellCheck()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProp = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), 
                typeof(DataCellCheck), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        public string Value
        {
            get { return GetValue(ValueProp) as String; }
            set { SetValue(ValueProp, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty StatusProp = 
            DependencyProperty.Register("Check", typeof(string), 
                typeof(DataCellCheck), new PropertyMetadata(""));

        public string Check
        {
            get { return GetValue(StatusProp) as String; }
            set { SetValue(StatusProp, value); }
        }
    }
```

3. So, what's happening here is that I am changing the `Background` color of my displayed `TextBlock` by binding it to a collapsed `Texblock`, in which I bind the `StressCheck` value from the viewModel in the following manner.

```
    public class TestViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        public Stress MyFirstStress { get; set; }

        public TestViewModel()
        {
            MyFirstStress = new Stress(1245, StressCheck.Fail);
        }

        public double DisplayStressValue => MyFirstStress.StressValue;
        public string DisplayStressCheck => MyFirstStress.Check.ToString();
    }
```

and in XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="ScienceProgram.Views.TestView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScienceProgram.Views"
             xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:ScienceProgram.UserControls"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="1200" d:DesignWidth="811">
    <Grid Margin="5">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="65"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel>
            <uc:DataCellCheck Value="{Binding Path=DisplayStressValue }" Check="{Binding Path=DisplayStressCheck}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

4. Now, my question is there a better way to trigger the color change in the displayed textblock, without having to bind `StressCheck` and hide it in another textblock?

Many many thanks.

Comment: Sorry. I cant really vote as I do not have enough points. And I was hoping to get different answers from others before I flagged your reply as the answer. But, I guess I wont be getting any more answers, as my question is kind of rudimentary. Anyway, here you go ! and thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a better way to trigger the color change in the displayed textblock, without having to bind StressCheck and hide it in another textblock?

I should hope so. The way you're doing it now is very kludgy.

Without a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it's impossible to confirm that this would work in your exact scenario, but it *should*. You can just bind to the `Check` property in the trigger instead of the other `TextBlock`:

```xml
<Style x:Key="CheckStress" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Check}" Value="Good">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Check}" Value="Bad">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

For what it's worth, I prefer to include a setter for one value and use triggers for the other (or others, if there are multiple):

```xml
<Style x:Key="CheckStress" TargetType="TextBlock">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Check}" Value="Bad">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Either way, WPF handles `enum` types implicitly, parsing a provided text value as the actual enum value and using it for the trigger's comparison. You don't need the extra `TextBlock` or other mechanism (such as a converter) to translate between the text you put in the XAML and the actual `enum` values.

If the above doesn't address your problem, please improve the question by providing a good MCVE so that the full context of your scenario can be understood.